# PyCharm is not getting along with OpenCV's imshow()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

In:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('My_Face.jpg')
cv2.imshow("My Face", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Out:

**: cannot connect to X server True**

Answer (score 0):

Your user doesn't have access to X-Server.

Provide access via terminal

```
xhost local:root
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I actually had DISPLAY = True in my environment variables. It worked fine when I removed it. Thank you for stepping by!